# Error with ng-serve while using ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular

I want show PDF in angular app in separate tab, used ng2-pdf-viewer.

Installed npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save

Am getting below error on ng-serve

> ERROR in
>   C:/Users/Kusha/TCSTDM/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/fesm5/ng2-pdf-viewer.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core' in 'C:\Users\Kusha\TCSTDM\node_modules\ng2-pdf-viewer\fesm5'
>       ERROR in C:/Users/Kusha/TCSTDM/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Kusha\TCSTDM\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build'
>       i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile. ERROR in ../../../node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts(4,105):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

app.module.ts

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
```

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdfguideview',
  templateUrl: './pdfguideview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdfguideview.component.css']
})
export class PdfguideviewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

html file

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer [src]="'assets/W2_2018.pdf'" 
[page]="1" 
[original-size]="true" 
style="display: block;">
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Comment: ng2-pdf-viewer and ng2-pdfjs-viewer are two different packages. :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of angular and pdf-viewer are you using?
This worked for me: 
`<pdf-viewer [src]="'assets/pdf-test.pdf'" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>`

Comment: ng2-pdf-viewer  5.3.3 version, any changes required in node modules or angular.json ?

Comment: No, I only noticed you used the selector <ng2-pdfjs-viewer> while in their implementation it says it should be <pdf-viewer>